# DateFormatter returns nil date for some users regardless of locale/isDaylightSavingTime/timezone

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

We use Disqus for our comments functionality. Its comments timestamp is in ISO8601 date format, e.g. `"2019-12-11T01:45:23"`. We tried to parse that string with DateFormatter, set up like this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
return dateFormatter
```

It works well for most users. However, we receive reports for a small amount of users that the formatter returns `nil`. Our initial hypothesis for the cause are as follows.

- the date format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" was wrong
- locale
- timezone
- daylight saving makes some time theoretically non-existent
- calendar
- or something else...

All of them are parameters we use to set up the DateFormatter. We tried many combinations, including ones we got from user reports. We tried the same date, locale, timezone, calendar, and the time itself as in user reports.

- locale: `en_GB`, timezone: `Europe/London`, calendar: gregorian, isDaylightSavingTime: 1
- locale: `en_TR`, timezone: `Etc/GMT-3`, calendar: gregorian, isDaylightSavingTime: 0
- locale: `es_MX`, timezone: `America/Mexico_City`, calendar: gregorian, isDaylightSavingTime: 1
- locale: `en_ID`, timezone: `Asia/Jakarta`, calendar: gregorian, isDaylightSavingTime: 0

But we could not reproduce.

Moreover, we did another test with a bunch of dates spreading throughout the year. And perform hidden parsing test on every user. It seems on device that returns nil date, it returns nil for EVERY date. The date string list looks like this...

```
    [
      "2019-01-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-02-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-03-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-04-10T01:45:23",
      "2019-04-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-04-12T01:45:23",
      "2019-05-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-06-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-07-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-08-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-09-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-10-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-11-11T01:45:23",
      "2019-12-11T01:45:23",
      ])
```

We later found that there is another date formatter called `ISO8601DateFormatter`. It seems to be more appropriate for this parsing. Here is the how we set it up.

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withTime, .withDashSeparatorInDate, .withColonSeparatorInTime]
return dateFormatter
```

With this `ISO8601DateFormatter`, the issue is fixed.

But I still want to know **what can cause `DateFormatter` to fail on some device**? Is there other factors than locale/isDaylightSavingTime/timezone that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Have you came up with any solution? I am getting nil regardless of whatever too.

Answer (score 2):

Is it the user's setting for 12-hour vs. 24-hour clock?

iOS can change a date formatter's format string to match the user's settings. The locale `en_US_POSIX` is [recommended for fixed formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html) to prevent format changes due to user settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ISO8601 date format with timezone

```
  "2019-12-11T01:45:23.000Z"
```

Format:

"XXXX-XX-XX" = year, month, day, 
"T" =  separator
"XX:XX:XX.XXX" = hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds
"Z" = timezone designator for zero offset, a.k.a. UTC, GMT, Zulu time

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
 return dateFormatter
```

Comment: It's from Disqus, a 3rd party service, so I have no control over the incoming date string format.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still facing this issue, what worked for me was to set `dateFormatter.isLenient = true` as it is described here: [DateFormatter returning nil for a valid Date string](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5967)